# Scala: is it possible to make a method "+" work like this: x + y = z?

Tags: scala

I have a graph, with each vertex connected to 6 neighbors.
While constructing the graph and making declarations of the connections, I would like to use a syntax like this:

```
1.    val vertex1, vertex2 = new Vertex
2.    val index = 3    // a number between 0 and 5
3.    vertex1 + index = vertex2
```

The result should be that `vertex2` be <strike>declared</strike> assigned as `index`-th neighbor of `vertex1`, equivalent to:

```
4.    vertex1.neighbors(index) = vertex2
```

While frobbing with the implementation of `Vertex.+`, I came up with the following:

```
5.    def +(idx: Int) = neighbors(idx)
```

which, very surprisingly indeed, did **not** cause line 3 to be underlined red by my IDE (IntelliJIdea, BTW).
However, compilation of line 3 offsprang the following message:

```
error: missing arguments for method + in class Vertex;
follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function
```

Next, I tried with an extractor, but actually, that doesn't seem to fit the case very well.

Does anybody have any clue if what I'm trying to achieve is anywhat feasible?

Thank you

Comment: Why `vertex1 + index = vertex2` and not `val vertex2 = vertex1 + index` if `vertex2` is the variable you want to declare?

Comment: The normal syntax in scala would be vertex1(index) = vertex2, which you get by defining a method def update(index: Int, vertex: V): Unit in Vertex. And no, you cannot define + to work like that. The best you could get is the clumsy (x + y)() = z

Comment: @sepp2k: that's not what I want to achieve. I'm editing the question to make it more clear.

Comment: @DidierDupont: yes, I get the point, I was hoping to find a way to avoid all those ugly parentheses. Actually `def update(i: Int, v: Vertex)` would have nicely done the trick... I just wanted to try out something more natural to me. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably can achieve what you want by using `:=` instead of `=`. Take a look at this illustrating repl session:

```
scala> class X { def +(x:X) = x; def :=(x:X) = x }
defined class X

scala> val a = new X;
a: X = X@7d283b68

scala> val b = new X;
b: X = X@44a06d88

scala> val c = new X;
c: X = X@fb88599

scala> a + b := c
res8: X = X@fb88599
```

As one of the comments stated,  the custom `=` requires two parameter, for example `vertex1(i)=vertex2` is dessugared to `vertext.update(i,vertex2)` thus forbidding the exact syntax you proposed. On the other hand `:=` is a regular custom operator and `a:=b` will dessugar to `a.:=(b)`.

Now we still have one consideration to do. Is the precedence going to work as you intent? The answer is yes, according to the [Language Specification section 6.12.3](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf). `+` has higher precedence than `:=`, so it ends up working as `(a+b):=c`.

Comment: I see... should I do something like: `def +(i: Int) = new Object { def :=(v: Vertex) { neighbors(i) = v } }` ?

Comment: I don't know, that depends on what you want, why can't := be defined in vertex itself?

Comment: Because I understand that calling the + method kind of adds state to the operation (which index to update). The `new Object` wraps this state information.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you want, just playing with right-associativity:

```
scala> class Vertex {
     |   val neighbors = new Array[Vertex](6)
     |   def :=< (n: Int) = (this, n)
     |   def >=: (conn: (Vertex, Int)) {
     |     val (that, n) = conn
     |     that.neighbors(n) = this
     |     this.neighbors((n+3)%6) = that
     |   }
     | }
defined class Vertex

scala> val a, b, c, d = new Vertex
a: Vertex = Vertex@c42aea
b: Vertex = Vertex@dd9f68
c: Vertex = Vertex@ca0c9
d: Vertex = Vertex@10fed2c

scala> a :=<0>=: b ; a :=<1>=: c ; d :=<5>=: a

scala> a.neighbors
res25: Array[Vertex] = Array(Vertex@dd9f68, Vertex@ca0c9, Vertex@10fed2c, null, null, null)
```